# I can not get data from jQuery Ajax submit Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel-5.7

Help me I am trying to received data from jQuery ajax submit by post in laravel 5.7. But I couldn't make it TT. I always get nothing in controller. And I've also tried to find it on laravel document and other sites. But I couldn't get any solutions. 
Here is my code.

- Route (web.php)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\OrderController;

Route::get('ajax', function(){
    return view("wash");
});
Route::post('getmsg', 'AjaxController@index');
```

- Route (web.php)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\OrderController;

Route::get('ajax', function(){
    return view("wash");
});
Route::post('getmsg', 'AjaxController@index');
```

- Controller (AjaxController.php)

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
class AjaxController extends Controller{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $id =  $request->input('id');

        $msg = "This is a simple message ".$id;
        return response()->json(array("msg"=>$msg), 200);
    }
}
```

- View (wash.blade.php)

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Ajax Example</title>
      <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </script>

      <script>
         function getMessage() {
             var dataString = { 
                     id : $(this).attr('id')
                   };

             $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "{{ URL::to('getmsg') }}",
                   data: dataString,
                   dataType: "json",
                   cache : false,
                   success: function(data){
                       $("#msg").html(data.msg);
                   }
                });
         }
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
          <div id = 'msg'>
              <p>This message will be replaced using Ajax.</p> 
              <p>Click the button to replace the message.</p>
          </div>
      <?php
         echo Form::button('Replace Message',['onClick'=>'getMessage()']);
      ?>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have tried it. But I get nothing

Comment: is there any error in js console?

Comment: no. I get only this in Network tap {msg: "This is a simple message "}

Comment: $(this).attr('id') ? the id is null here which id you want the rest of code is fine just pass and id

Comment: Oop I get it. $request->id; is right. If i want to get all inputs, How to do it?

Comment: use $request->all();

Comment: $input = $request->all(); $input["id"]; It works. thanks